# php-Mysql Write a Group By query issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called comparitive_st_sup. The structure is as follows:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ tender_id ║ item_name ║ ifmain ║ total ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    400    ║  Item 1   ║  Yes   ║ 2000  ║
║  2 ║    400    ║  Item 2   ║  Yes   ║ 2500  ║
║  3 ║    400    ║  Item 3   ║  No    ║ 2000  ║
║  4 ║    400    ║  Item 4   ║  No    ║ 2900  ║
║  5 ║    400    ║  Item 5   ║  Yes   ║ 3100  ║
║  6 ║    402    ║  Item 9   ║  Yes   ║ 877   ║
║  7 ║    402    ║  Item 7   ║  No    ║ 9888  ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Now i need to group by tender_id and ifmain and show totals. For example:

```
 400  Yes  7600 (2000 + 2500 + 3100 that is ifmain=Yes)
 400  No   4900 (2000 + 2900 that is ifmain=No)
```

I tried the below query. but its not working:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(total) AS maintotal,
 SUM(total) AS subtotal, fmain 
FROM comparitive_st_sup 
WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' 
GROUP BY ifmain
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a two step `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tender_id, ifmain, SUM(total)
FROM comparative_st_sup
WHERE tender_id='$tender_id'            # replace with any WHERE condition you want
GROUP BY tender_id, ifmain
```

I have retained the `WHERE` clause which appeared in your original query.  If you change the `WHERE` condition to a range, or anything which give a result set containing more than one unique `tender_id`, then my `GROUP BY` will come in handy.

Click the link below for a demo of the query:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d5bf/1)

**Update:**

If you want to see the `Yes` and `No` sums as separate columns in your result set, you can try a query along these lines:

```
SELECT tender_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'Yes' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS maintotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'No' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal,
FROM comparative_st_sup
WHERE tender_id='$tender_id'
GROUP BY tender_id
```

Again, you can change the `WHERE` clause to suit your needs, or remove it altogether.

Comment: Why to use `tender_id` within `group by` clause as its been already result those values that have `tender_id`

Comment: yes if i remove tender_id from group by also its works fine.. Is there a way i can i can split or identity which is maintotal and which is subtotal? Example ifmain=Yes is Maintotal, ifmain=No is subtotal. sum(total) as maintotal, sum(total) as subtotal???

Comment: Are you telling us you want the `Yes` and `No` sums as separate columns?

Comment: Yes Mr. Tim. If i can show totals Yes and No in seperate column?

Answer (score 0):

Group By using two fields :

```
Select sum(total) as maintotal, sum(total) as subtotal, fmain 
from comparitive_st_sup 
where tender_id='$tender_id' 
group by ifmain, ifmain
```